# Display nickname instead of ID number of a table

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have two tables:

**users**

```
id nickname
1   Mike
2   John
```

**report**

```
id    user_id   target_id
1       1          2     
2       2          1
```

**MyController**

```
public function violationView(User $user)
{   
    $vio = Report::all(); //this should be query, but I don't know how.
    return view('admin.violation.vio_listpage')
            ->with('vio', $vio);
}
```

When I displayed the `$vio` into my blade, it only displays the `user_id` and `target_id`. These should be the **nickname** of the users and not ID number.

**Expected Output**

```
ID   user_name(user_id)   username(target_id)
1      Mike                  John
2      John                  Mike
```

Does anybody know how to display the nickname instead if `user_id` and `target_id`?

Comment: You should join the 2 tables

Comment: yeah, I just edited to Report. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get user name by user id you need to add join with in your query. Below is the example for that:-

```
$vio = Violation::join('users', function($q) {
        $q->on('users.id', '=', 'report.user_id');
    })
    ->join('users as target', function($q) {
        $q->on('target.id', '=', 'report.target_id');
    })
    ->selectRaw("report.*, users.nickname as user_name, target.nickname as target_user_name")
    ->get();
return view('admin.violation.vio_listpage')
        ->with('vio', $vio);
```

Try this. I think this will help you to achieve your goal.

Comment: Woww. thank you. this is correct. Please remove the downvote.